# Jupyter notrebook installation for pycharm on windows version 6.3.9600 and python 3.8.0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Each time I try to install jupyter notebook in pycharm with pip install jupyter, I get the following error:

I have already searched for some solutions and reinstalled the pywin32 and checked the versions of the system_platform, python and the pip/pipenv but nothing changed the following error:

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Collecting pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)

Does anybodyhas a solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you please try with Python 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug. I uninstalled Python 3.8.1, then I installed Python 3.7.5, then PyCharm was able to install Jupyter.